# horizontal menu that swipes with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, horizontal-scrolling

The client wants me to build a dropdown menu that swipes and shows dropdown menu when hover/clicked (cause it's for mobile version too).

The problem causes overflow-x that is hiding dropdown and it has to show over the box.
Is there any solution for this?

```
<ul class="scroll-menu">
    <li class="scroll-one">HOME</li>
    <li class="scroll-one">CATEGORY 1
    <ul class="drop-w">
        <li class="dropp">dropdown</li>
        <li class="dropp">dropdown</li>
        <li class="dropp">dropdown</li>
        <li class="dropp">dropdown</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="scroll-one">CATEGORY 2</li>
    <li class="scroll-one">CATEGORY 3</li>
    <li class="scroll-one">CATEGORY 4</li>
    <li class="scroll-one">CATEGORY 5</li>
    <li class="scroll-one">CATEGORY 6</li>
</ul>


.scroll-menu .scroll-one {
display: inline-block;
width:115px;
padding: 1%;

position: relative;

    list-style: none;
}
.scroll-one:hover .drop-w {
    display: inline-block;
}
.drop-w {
    display: inline-block;

    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

For demo I built dropdown menu only on Category1.
https://jsfiddle.net/just_vr/ye483e4v/7/

Please help. Thanks

Comment: can you please more explain? you want to show menu after scrollbar?

Comment: Yes, after scrollbar.

Comment: «Computed value: as specified, except with visible computing to `auto` if one of `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` is not `visible`.»
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment by blonfu, you cannot have overflow-x scroll and overflow-y visible (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties). overflow-y automatically becomes auto, which means a scrollbar appears for vertical as well.

If you want horizontal scroll and vertical dropdown, you'll have to do it programmatically using javascript. One way I can suggest is:

1. Take the dropdowns out of the parent ul and make them separate lists, but within the parent nav element which should be parent of the main nav ul.
2. link them up using id's or classes with their parent element.
3. Using javascript, on selecting a parent element through click, get the current position of the main nav element with respect to the parent container and then give those positions to the relevant submenu element, and display them.
4. Could do the same for mouse over event as well if you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

I built this based on your answer https://jsfiddle.net/just_vr/hhLL6ga6/1/

It was really helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of help!